# Show that any two closed and bounded interval are homeomorphic in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

> Any two closed and bounded intervals are homeomorhpic in $\mathbb{R}$:
>
> If we want to show that the two sets $[a,b]$ and $[a_1,b_1]$ are homeomorphic we can consider the following map $f(x) \mapsto \frac{(x-a)}{b-a}(b_1-a_1) + a_1$. This map is continuous and bijective and the inverse of the map  is also continuous.

However here are the follow up questions I have asked myself and I am stuck with -

1)What if the intervals are not bounded - Is $[a,b]$ hoemeomorphic to $[a_1,\infty)$?

I don't think it would hold because $[0,1]$ is probably not homeomorphic to $[1,\infty)$.

2)Is there a way to generalize this in $\mathbb{R}^n$- Any set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (under the product metric ) is closed iff it is of the form $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$ where each $A_i$ is closed. Assume that each $A_i,B_i$ is closed and bounded then is $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$ homeomorphic to $B_1 \times \cdots \times B_n$?

I think this would hold true because $A_i$ and $B_i$ are closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ and let us consider $f_i:A_i \mapsto B_i$ where $f_i$ is a homeomorphism. Then $f(x) = (f_1,\cdots f_n(x))$ might be the homeomorphism we are looking for.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: @5xum I have added my thoughts but this is something I wanted to ask whether in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under any norm the closed sets are of the form $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$ where each $A_i$ is closed.

Comment: Maybe this is not true under a metric which is not a norm . However, do I have an example?

Comment: about point 2) : beware, there are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are NOT of the form $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$ where each $A_i$ is closed.

Comment: @OlivierRoche under the product metric? Can you give such an example?

Comment: @5xum I am not sure how to proceed with $1$. Can't think of any such map..

Comment: @ThirstForMaths consider the complement of the open unit ball.

PS : read this carrefully : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology

Notice that the products of open sets form a BASIS for the topology .

Comment: If we consider the open ball $B((0,0);\epsilon)$ in the product metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $B((0,0);\epsilon) = B(0;\epsilon) \times B(0,\epsilon)$ then the complement isn't it og the form $A_1 \times A_2$ where $A_1 = \mathbb{R} - B(0;\epsilon)$ and $A_2 =  \mathbb{R} - B(0;\epsilon)$ where both are closed?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths if there is such a homeomorphism , then Homeomorphic image of compact set will be non compact. Compactness is a topological property (preserved by Homeomorphism)

Comment: @ThirstForMaths Draw what you said, and draw the complement of the ball, you'll see they don't match

Comment: @S.G. If $f$ is a homeomorhpism then , $f([a,b]) = [a,\infty)$ the image of compact sets is compact and $[a,\infty)$ is not compact. Hence there is no homeomorphism between both.Is this reasoning okay?

Comment: @Didier - So $B((0,0);\epsilon)$ is giving be a box centered at $(0,0)$ with length and width being $\epsilon$. However, the complement is no way in which I can write in terms of $A_1 \times A_2$.

Comment: @ThirstForMaths Yes. The product $(\Bbb R \setminus (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon))^2$ is the plane with an "infinite cross" removed (the union of the two bands $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times \Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R \times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon))$, which isn't the complement of the box

Comment: Yes,@Didier Can you go through my reasoning as to why (1) doesn't happen - If $f$ is a homeomorhpism then , $f([a,b])=[a,\infty)$ the image of compact sets is compact and $[a,\infty)$ is not compact. Hence there is no homeomorphism between both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[0,1]$ is **not** homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ because the former has two non-cutpoints and the latter just one. Or the former is compact and the latter is not. So you cannot just blithely extend...

And in $\Bbb R^n$ it's very definitely **not** true that closed sets must be of the form $A_1 \times A_2 \ldots \times A_n$ as standard closed sets of the plane (lines, the $xy$-axes, graphs and circles...) already show. Such sets *are* closed (when all $A_i$ are) but the variation in more dimensions is immense. So get that notion out of your head ASAP!